# Why does this ZSH if-statement does not load with new console session?

Tags: if-statement, awk, zsh

I have this if-statment in my ZSH config file that does not load when a console session starts, but the rest of the file does.

```
then
alias sd="dirs -v | awk 'NR>1' | awk '!seen[$2]++'"
else
alias sd="dirs -v | awk 'NR>1'"
fi
```

Also, if I load the config file from within the session with `exec zsh`, it does work.

Any idea why?

Comment: Separate from whatever other issues you may be having (which we can't diagnose because you aren't giving enough details), the `$2` isn't going to behave the way you want in the `if` branch, because it's in a double-quoted context (the more immediate single-quotes are literal). You'll have an easier time of this with a function -- `sd() { dirs -v | awk 'NR>1' | awk '!seen[$2]++'; }` f/e (though it's a little silly to have two `awk` calls when you only need one).

Comment: One issue, btw, is that you aren't telling us **which** zsh config file you're putting this in. `.zprofile` is loaded for _login_ shells, f/e, whereas `.zshrc` is loaded for _interactive_ shells. We don't know which config file you're putting this in so we don't know which kind of shell is expected to load it.

Comment: I suggest to use a function for this.

Comment: By default, an `alias` does not work in a script and the `alias` no longer exists when the script is finished.

Comment: `alias` is very rarely the appropriate thing to use.

Comment: @Cyrus: We are talking about zsh here! aliases in scripts (i.e. non-interactive zsh) work by default. Don't know whether you can turn them off.

Comment: You haven't said which config file you used, and you haven't said how you started the zsh where the aliases are not present. How can you expect help if you don't reveal such crucial details?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for the tip. Formatting it as a function did the trick. It was in the .zshrc file, but now, I moved it to a separate file that I source from .zshrc.

I do not know how to fuse the awk commands into 1, so for now, it will stay like this. Feel free to post the comment as an answer and I will tick it as the solution.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an alias with double-quotes wrapping the outside, `$2` is prone to being expanded. Beyond that, alias support is turned off by default in scripts.

Consider a function:

```
sd() { dirs -v | awk 'NR>1 && !seen[$2]++'; }
```